# Distorted Page Number Images Of Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that I have created in Jquery with following code.

```
 //Creating Kendo Grid For Tasks
            divSearchGrid.kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: function (options) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: urlSearch,
                                data: paramsSearch,
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (result) {
                                    if (data != null) {
                                        if (data.length > 0) {
                                            orignalComplexData = data; 
                                            options.success(orignalComplexData )
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            divSearchGrid.html('<h4>No records To Display</h4>')
                                            // To stop the Auto Refresh of the grid if there are no results
                                            isEditing = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        divSearchGrid.html('<h4>Some Error Occured</h4>')
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                batch: true,
                edit: function (e) {

                    // To stop the Auto Refresh of the grid on edit
                    isEditing = true;
                },
                groupable: true,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                resizable: true,
                selectable: "row",               
                autoSync: true,
                editable: true,
                navigatable: true,
                columns: columnList,
                columnMenu: true,
                filterable: true,
                columnMenu: {
                    sortable: false
                },
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
            });    
        }
```

Everything works fine but in the pager of the grid the images of page number are getting distorted. See the below Image for a better idea.

[image]

Can Someone give me some pointers to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like something that comes from kendo (I've never seen it at least), each of the pager buttons consists of a hyperlink in a list element like this:

```
<li>
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="k-link" data-page="1">1</a> 
</li>
```

You're probably adding your own custom bullet point for the `<li>` element, which is why it's adding the square bullet. Remove your custom styling and it should be okay.

If you're trying to customize kendo UI themes, it's probably better to use their [themebuilder](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/web.html).

If you are not trying to use a custom Kendo theme and you're just customizing an ordinary HTML list somewhere, make sure you use a very specific selector in your CSS and do not decorate generic HTML elements.

I have reproduced your distortion:

[image: Distorted pager buttonz]

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party controls/tools?

Comment: I can reproduce your case (see the image above). Maybe you have not done any customizations yourself, but by adding obscure third party controls/libraries, it may bring in badly written styles sheets. Fastest way for you to check is just inspect the element and determine where that square bullet is coming from, __something__ is overriding the generic `li` element

Comment: Hey Thanks the solution worked yes there was an overriding css and after removing it the pager came properly.